# What is wrong with my AWS Amazon Athena query? line 2:10: extraneous input ''ticket_id'' expecting {'add', 'all',..}

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Here is my query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cw-milenko"."calc-milenko" (
  'ticket_id' string, 'sum_stake' float, 'amount_stake_one' string, ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'serialization.format' = '1') location 's3://cw-milenko-tests/1507tick2.parquet/part-00000-bbab8f70-4758-4041-9f69-c17f21c916dac000.snappy.parquet'
```

I got this error:

```
line 2:10: extraneous input ''ticket_id'' expecting {'add', 'all', 'some', 'any', 'at', 'no', 'like', 'substring', 'position', 'tinyint', 'smallint', 'integer', 'date', 'time', 'timestamp', 'interval', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'zone', 'filter', 'over', 'partition', 'range', 'rows', 'preceding', 'following', 'current', 'row', 'schema', 'comment', 'view', 'replace', 'grant', 'revoke', 'privileges', 'public', 'option', 'explain', 'analyze', 'format', 'type', 'text', 'graphviz', 'logical', 'distributed', 'validate', 'show', 'tables', 'views', 'schemas', 'catalogs', 'columns', 'column', 'use', 'partitions', 'functions', 'to', 'system', 'bernoulli', 'poissonized', 'tablesample', 'array', 'map', 'set', 'reset', 'session', 'data', 'start', 'transaction', 'commit', 'rollback', 'work', 'isolation', 'level', 'serializable', 'repeatable', 'committed', 'uncommitted', 'read', 'write', 'only', 'call', 'input', 'output', 'cascade', 'restrict', 'including', 'excluding', 'properties', 'function', 'lambda_invoke', 'returns', 'sagemaker_invoke_endpoint', 'nfd', 'nfc', 'nfkd', 'nfkc', 'if', 'nullif', 'coalesce', identifier, digit_identifier, quoted_identifier, backquoted_identifier} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: c53879fc-4fe9-4e33-b197-a9adcab48677)
```

What does this mean? How should my query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the below things should resolve the issue with your query and if not you have to post the exact query that you have executed in Athena.

1. Never use dashes (-) in Database, table , column names while creating tables. Yes you can create them fine by applying backticks but the actual problem appears when you try querying them. Every time you need to append this backticks around them to solve the problem.Check special characters section in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html).
2. Also never point location to absolute path of the file and instead it has to be `s3://cw-milenko-tests/1507tick2.parquet/` in your case. [Check out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html) this to know more about this.
3. Also remove the tailing comma from the query posted. I think this came in because you might have removed some part of your query and posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things

- There is a trailing coma in you column definition
- Use backticks for column, table and database names instead of quotes (don't think this is important in your case though)
- `LOCATION` can't be set to a single file

The following should work

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cw-milenko`.`calc-milenko` (
  `ticket_id` string, 
  `sum_stake` float, 
  `amount_stake_one` string
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) 
LOCATION 's3://cw-milenko-tests/1507tick2.parquet/'
```

### EDIT 2020-07-17

As pointed out by [Prabhakar Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4326922/prabhakar-reddy) you can't set location to a single file (reference to [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html))

Comment: you cannot create a table in Athena pointing to a file in Athena.